# How to pass data from parent to child (react Modal)?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-props

I have a page **users.jsx** (parent) and a component **DialogEditUser.jsx** (child) and i would like to pass a specific data of a user that is located in parent to child by it's `id` (using `find` method)

This passed data should be loaded to its input in react modal as a value.

**users.jsx** Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import DialogAddUser from 'src/components/DialogAddUser'
import { getUsers} from 'src/Service/api'

const Typography = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllUsers()
  }, [])

  const deleteUserData = async (id) => {
    setConfirmDialog({
      ...setConfirmDialog,
      isOpen: false,
    })
    await deleteUser(id)
    getAllUsers()
    setNotify({
      isOpen: true,
      message: 'Article Deleted Successfully.',
      type: 'error',
    })
  }

  const getAllUsers = async () => {
    let response = await getUsers()
    setUsers(response.data)
    console.log(response.data)
  }
return ( //... )
```

**DialogEditUsers.jsx** Code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getUsers, editUser } from '../Service/api'

const initialValue = {
  id: '',
  code: '',
  article: '',
  price: '',
  vat: '',
  status: '',
  company_id: '',
}

export default function DialogAddUser() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(initialValue)
  const { code, article, price, vat, status, company_id } = user

  const normalize = (v) => ({
    code: v.code,
    article: v.article,
    price: Number(v.price),
    vat: Number(v.vat),
    status: Number(v.status),
    company_id: Number(v.company_id),
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    loadUserDetails()
  }, [])

  const loadUserDetails = async () => {
    const response = await getUsers(id)
    console.log('loading user details ', response)
    setUser(response.data.find((x) => x.id == id))
  }

  const editUserDetails = async () => {
    const response = await editUser(id, normalize(user))
    console.log('Edit user details ', response)
  }

  const onValueChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
return (
    <>
      <CModal
        visible={visible}
        onClose={() => setVisible(false)}
        backdrop={'static'}
        keyboard={false}
        portal={false}
      >
        <CModalHeader>
          <CModalTitle>Edit Article:</CModalTitle>
        </CModalHeader>
        <CModalBody>
          <CForm>
            <CFormInput
              type="text"
              id="exampleFormControlInput1"
              label="Code :"
              placeholder="Enter Code"
              text=" "
              aria-describedby="exampleFormControlInputHelpInline"
              onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
              value={code}
              name="code"
            />
            <CFormInput
              type="text"
              id="exampleFormControlInput2"
              label="Article :"
              placeholder="Enter Article"
              text=" "
              aria-describedby="exampleFormControlInputHelpInline"
              onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
              value={article}
              name="article"
            />
//...the rest of inputs...
```

**api.js** Code:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const baseURL = 'https://api.factarni.tn/article'

const token =
  'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIxZTZjMGM2YjRlMzA5NTI0N2MwNjgwMDAwZTFiNDMxODIzODZkNTAiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.bvRTxHfPtJrQjF2BjXqhs7ji738kma55LMFVRb8jkeraWP-JRBi-LRPa0d7OR_-BPwCGuRBXIb6980_PP8wjhBeDdB5B77GujiGn3nUvpPOFeIaM0L7muw1NKo4YCtS3v6ifuywypTbL3_5x3SBFZEH-QV0sp5DAzaA-P3Fn8AwP66o3cUPHGengGpZNsfkJ0FYcqzH-xpyKVVWV'
//i dont mind sharing this token, it's for you to test this code if you need.

const config = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }

export const getUsers = async (id) => {
  id = id || ''
  try {
    return await axios.get(`${baseURL}`, config)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error while calling getArticles api ', error)
  }
}

export const editUser = async (id, user) => {
  return await axios.put(`${baseURL}/${id}`, user, config)
}
```

The only node error i'm getting in terminal using this code above (because i dont know how to pass the proper id of specified user) is:

```
src\components\DialogEditUser.jsx
  Line 45:37:  'id' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 47:47:  'id' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 51:37:  'id' is not defined  no-undef
```

---

**For better explanation the problem** (i dont know how to use online snippets sorry):

So *what i'm expecting* is: When i click on Edit button, i should get a modal with form that are filled with user data (`code`, `article`, `price`, `vat`, `status` and `company_id`) in each input of the form as value, just like this gif below:

[image: gif]

Also, `console.log(response.data)` in users page shows this:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **users.jsx**, pass props of (user.id):

```
<DialogEditArticle props={user.id} />
```

Then, in **DialogEditArticle.jsx**, create a new data and call in it `props`:

```
const DialogEditArticle = (data) => {
  console.log(data.props)
```

Now console.dev, you will get all the ids of user in database (because button edit is inside `map` function).
**Result**:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

few days back i also faced the same issue. Solution for me is to create state in parent component and pass state to child. Example for it-

**Parent Class**

```
const parent= ()=>{
const [name, setName]= useState('')
const [password, setPassword]= useState('')
return(
<Child setName={setName} setPassword={setPassword} />
)
}
```

**Child Class**

```
const Child = ({setPassword,setName})=>{
return(
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
</div>
)
}
```

Hope my answer will help you to solve your problem, if you still facing issue, lemme know i will help you.